# Is it possible to generate LightBox2 galleries from Adobe Lightroom?

Tags: lightbox2, lightroom

I'm a frequent Adobe Lightroom user, and there are many options to export pictures. Unfortunately, I don't find anything to allow the export to LightBox2 galleries.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate web galleries with Adobe Lightroom using a pre-made set of  HTML and Flash templates. These templates allow simple customizations, such as color, layout, and watermarks, but do not allow the changing of interactions or adding custom plugins like Lightbox.

To add Lightbox to an Adobe Lightroom web gallery you will have to make the additions manually after the gallery is generated. You can follow the steps on the official Lightbox page:
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started

More information about Adobe Lightroom Web Galleries:
https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/creating-web-galleries-basic-workflow.html